# Cannot run Gulp locally

Tags: javascript, gulp, require

I have a simple web application that is growing in complexity, so I want to use a build tool like Gulp to allow me to do things like compile SCSS to CSS and minimize my JavaScript files before uploading my website.

I followed different tutorials (for example [this one](https://css-tricks.com/gulp-for-beginners/)) but when testing it by running the command `gulp hello` in VS Code, I get the error

> ReferenceError: require is not defined

Looking around, it seems like I cannot use `require` in client-side JavaScript and that I need to add some tool like "browserify" too, but this is just adding to the complexity of my simple application. Is there no way to get around this error and use Gulp for simple client-side applications? Is there some other tool I should be using to simplify my workflow?

Comment: I would suggest something all-in-one for your web app, rather than combining gulp and browserify. Vite is very easy to get started with ( https://vitejs.dev ) and lets you use ES Modules, SCSS, and other stuff. Projects like Parcel ( https://parceljs.org ) will also offer a unified experience. Webpack will require more setup ( https://webpack.js.org ) but would be the most flexible.

I definitely suggest giving Vite and ES Modules a try.

Comment: @knpwrs Thanks a million for your help. I tried Vite at first according to your suggestion, but it seemed like Webpack might be more flexible like you said. However, I've been struggling with this problem (https://stackoverflow.com/q/69508269/2784835) all day. Do you know what the issue might be? Thanks again.